# GOOGLEFINANCE - How to get Amsterdam data?

Tags: google-finance

I want to get market data for the shares listed in Euronext Amsterdam (for example '[Royal Dutch Shell plc (RDSB.AS)](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RDSB.AS?p=RDSB.AS&.tsrc=fin-srch)'). [Google's Finance Data Listing](https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer) says that for the Euronext Amsterdam the symbol 'AMS' needs to be used as a prefix for a ticker.

When I am using the following command...

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AEX:RDSB"; "price")
```

...then I am getting the error message:
`"When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'RDSB' returned no data."`

So, what's wrong with my code? Isn't it possible to get the Amsterdam Stock Exchange market data? If so, then why the Euronext Amsterdam is listed in exchanges list?

Everything works fine for the London Stock Exchange:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("LON:RDSB"; "price")
```

Answer (score 6):

You gave your own answer: "Google's Finance Data Listing says that for the Euronext Amsterdam the symbol 'AMS' needs to be used as a prefix for a ticker."
Use AMS instead of AEX.
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMS:RDSB"; "price")